# Force reload when url hash changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, hash

In my application there is a header menu. We have 5 menu items with same page url with different hash values such as

1. Home (www.sample.com)
2. Brand page 1(www.sample.com/test.html#brand1)
3. Brand page 2(www.sample.com/test.html#brand2)
4. Brand page 3(www.sample.com/test.html#brand3)
5. Brand page 4(www.sample.com/test.html#brand4)

All the brand pages will be navigated to the same page (test.html) but with different hash.

Problem: when I click any of the links of brand page from **HOME**, the page automatically navigates to test.html and check for hash tag and loads item through ajax automatically.

But when I click any of the brand page links inside the brand page, the page is not refreshing.

Comment: onhashchange=location.reload.bind(location);

Comment: Thanks @dandavis But this does not works in IE

Comment: it can work in IE8+, might want to use an anon instead of bind for ie8. that said, it's seems like a really bad idea and defeats the point of a single page site to reload each navigation...

Comment: is there a specific need that you try to bend the natural behaviour of hash? maybe use url params instead `www.sample.com/test.html?brand1` or even something like `www.sample.com/test.html?p=0#brand1`. You won't have to worry about browser compatibility this way...

Answer (score 5):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="#1">brand 1</a>
    <a href="#2">brand 2</a>
</div>
```

**JQ:**

```
$(function() {

    $('#menu a').click(function(e){
        var url=$(this).attr('href');

        window.location.href=url;// ## change url with hash
        location.reload();       // ## reload page

        e.preventDefault();      // ## prevent default click action 
    })

})
```